# How to handle nested loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array, nested

I would like to process nested loop.
Here is what I did.

```
num_list = [1, 2]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b']
for number in num_list:
    print(number)
    for letter in alpha_list:
        print(letter)
```

This is will output:

```
1
a
b
2
a
b
```

But my expectation output is like this:

```
1
a
2
b
```

or

```
1a
2b
```

Anyone can give idea please. Thank you

Comment: The nested loop runs for for each value of the outer loop, so it's not the proper tool for your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zip` function.

```py
for n, a in zip(num_list, alpha_list):
    print(n, a)
```

`zip` stops when the shorter of `n` or `a` stops.

Answer (score 1):

you can use zip:

```
num_list = [1, 2]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b']
for number,letter in zip(num_list,alpha_list):
    print(number)
    print(letter)
```

Or:

```
num_list = [1, 2]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b']
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    print(num_list[i])
    print(alpha_list[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

below snippet will give you the desired result:

```
num_list = [1, 2]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b']
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    print(str(num_list[i])+str(alpha_list[i])) # Concatenate the elements of the two lists
```

Answer (score 1):

To archive your goal you need something like this:

```
num_list = [1, 2]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b']

for _ in range(len(num_list)):
  print(num_list[_])
  print(alpha_list[_])
```

In your example you go into the first item from num_list and inside the loop you go through the complete second list. Then second item and again whole second list.

So to manage multiple lists in one for loop you have to work with the index or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a liner problem, nested loops are invalid here. You need to pass on each element of the arrays simultaneously.

```
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    print(num_list[i], alpha_list[i], end='\n')
```

Even simpler using python `zip` function:

```
for pair in zip(num_list, alpha_list):
    print('\n'.join(map(str, pair)))
```

You can change `'\n'` to whatever separator you like between a letter and a number.